# response of `vars(self)` is missing attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots

I have defined a class and need most of its attributes handed over to a function for processing. So I thought instead of creating a huge mess and naming them all I'd do `processSomething(vars(self))` and hand over a nice dictionary with all attributes and values.

But I found that almost all of the attributes are missing.

I have halted the code in the debugger and ran a few tests:

```
>>> vars(self).keys()
dict_keys(['date_expire', 'tokenUrl', 'settings', 'requestSession', 'ttlDays'])
```

These are 5. While I am expecting about 20 attributes, as per `__slots__` definition of my class here:

```
__slots__ = (
    'token',        # the invitation-token to load the username with
    'request',      # the http-request which is currently being serviced
    'inhibit',      
     #... many lines deleted
    'templateObj',  # an instance of myMail.template.Template
    'emailBody',    # what will be sent via SMTP
    'warningsAr',   # messages for the client
)
```

I can see the attributes in the debugger window and can access them directly. I have read the [manual of vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) and could not find any switches. Interestingly, `dir(self)` shows all attribute-names, but no values. So I cannot use that. But I thought vars and dir should show the same?

I guess I'll build a workaround, but I really want to understand what is happening here. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vars()` returns you the `__dict__` namespace of an instance. But `__slots__` attributes are *not stored in the `__dict__` namespace*. That's their whole point.

Instead, Python creates dedicated pointer slots in the instance memory structure for each value, and uses *descriptors* on the class object to retrieve those values. So `inst.attr` is translated to `type(inst).attr.__get__(inst)` to return that value.

From the [`__slots__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.
>
> *[...]*
>
> - `__slots__` are implemented at the class level by creating descriptors ([Implementing Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors)) for each variable name.

Note that having a `__dict__` *anyway* is usually a sign you forgot to make a subclass use `__slots__` for their attributes, or you inherited from a base Python class that didn't use `__slots__` itself. Proper use of `__slots__` should result in instances with no `__dict__` namespace; their goal is to reduce memory by avoiding the sparse hash table required for a dict (which can waste space).

From the documentation again:

> - When inheriting from a class without `__slots__`, the `__dict__` attribute of that class will always be accessible, so a `__slots__` definition in the subclass is meaningless.
>
> *[...]*
>
> - The action of a `__slots__` declaration is limited to the class where it is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a `__dict__` unless they also define `__slots__` (which must only contain names of any additional slots).

If you wanted to list all available instance fields, you'd have to include the `__slots__` enumeration from the class, and not just look at `vars()`:

```
from itertools import chain

def slots_for_instance(inst):
    def _slots_for_class(c):
        slots = getattr(c, '__slots__', ())
        if isinstance(slots, str):
            # __slots__ can be a string naming a single attribute
            slots = (slots,)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(
        getattr(_slots_for_class(c) for c in type(inst).__mro__))
```

Comment: Makes sense. Not sure tho why dir() is behaving so differently by giving me all vars. Thank you.
ACCEPTED! *stamp*

Comment: @Chris: `dir()` is a different beast altogether, see [what's the biggest difference between dir and \_\_dict\_\_ in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/14361256)